# Mock opening file in unit test in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to unit test a function given below:

```
def _get_file(file_name):
    """
    Retrieves file.
    :param file_name: file
    :return:
    """
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(DIR, file_name), 'r') as file:
            contents = file.read()
    except Exception as FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error(FileNotFoundError)
    else:
        file.close()
        return contents
```

I have written the following unit test to test the above function. However I also want to check the conditon where exception is raised if file not found. How can I go about it ?

```
 @patch('__builtin__.open', create=True)
 def test_get_file(self, mock_file):
        """Tests opening and closing of file."""
        fake_file = io.StringIO(u"contents\n")
        mock_file.return_value = fake_file
        result = _get_file('filename')
        self.assertEquals(result, u'contents\n')
```

Comment: What is `query`. Please provide the entire function if you need help testing it

Comment: I have edited the question, it just returns contents